# PHP–FPM + Apache proxy_fcgi error message customization

Tags: apache, php, mod-proxy

Is there a way to customize or change a message which is returned if PHP-FPM file not found?

In my virtual hosts file I have:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/path/to/socket.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/my/documentroot/
```

When I want to access php file which is not there (just for error testing) it displays 'File not found.', not Apache 404 error document.

Basically **I would like that ProxyPassMatch would redirect to Apache 404 error, if file not found**. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, add this after your **ProxyPassMatch** setting:

```
 ProxyErrorOverride on
```

To set your customer error page, you need this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/file
```

Comment: Php-fpm traps errors within its own context, so this won't work. It simply displays a single text line, "File not found". Absent a way to trap this in php-fpm and serve a proper ErrorDocument (which I haven't yet found), the redirection has to be done in some other context of the tool-chain. I'm using FastCGI + php-fpm and haven't found a way to do this yet.